ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor Server App - A suitable constructor could not be located
I have tried numerous approaches, unsuccessfully, to get the connection string from appsettings.json. If this is not the best approach, what approach would work?
Runtime error:

System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'App.Services.DataService' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public constructor are either registered as services or passed as arguments. Also ensure no extraneous arguments are provided.

appsettings.json:
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Database1": "Server=_____.____.____;Database=______;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
    }
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>
              (builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataService, DataService>();

ConnectionStrings.cs:
public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public string Database1 { get; set; }
}

DataService.cs:
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    private readonly ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;

    public DataService(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
    {
        _connectionStrings = connectionStrings.Value;
    }
}

Page.razor:
@inject IDataService DataService 

...

_elements = await DataService.GetElementsByTerm(term);
...


Hi @Jim, how do you register the service? Also, how do you implement the IDataService and call it in razor component? Pls share enough code.

A whole working demo you could follow:
1.Be sure register DataService in Program.c
builder.Services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));

// Register DataService with dependency injection
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataService, DataService>();

2.Implement the service
public interface IDataService
{
    string GetDatabaseName();
}
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    private readonly ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;

    public DataService(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
    {
        _connectionStrings = connectionStrings.Value;
    }

    public string GetDatabaseName()
    {
        var db = _connectionStrings.Database1;
        return db;
    }
}

3.Call service in Razor Component
@page "/"
@inject IDataService DataService

<h3>Data Service Example</h3>
@db

@code {
    public string db { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        db = DataService.GetDatabaseName();
    }
}


Rena beat me to an answer.  Mine was the same except I was going to have ConnectionStrings as a record.  It's readonly so make it so.  public record ConnectionStrings() {     public static string SectionName = "ConnectionStrings";     public string? Database1 { get; init; } } 
